# Spring boot Cron is not working from the second day

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I am trying to run the server locally which has Spring boot cron expression. For the first day cron is working fine but from the next cron expression is not getting triggered.

@Component
public class MailScheduler {

```
  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 9 ? * *")
  public void sendMail(){
    System.out.println("*****************Mail Started");
  }
}
```

I have added @EnableScheduling in  main class. First day everything looks good but from second it is not working. If I restart the server on that particular day cron is getting triggered but from second day not getting triggered.
Second day Logs:

> > 2021-05-18 12:00:00.012  INFO 20520 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> > DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2021-05-18 12:00:00.012  INFO
> > 20520 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
> > Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2021-05-18 12:00:00.014  INFO
> > 20520 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
> > Completed initialization in 2 ms 2021-05-18 14:06:39.148  WARN 20520
> > --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper
> > delta=17m20s769ms350µs701ns). 2021-05-18 21:19:58.233  WARN 20520 ---
> > [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        :
> > HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper
> > delta=31m42s577ms997µs900ns). 2021-05-19 07:20:11.126  WARN 20520 ---
> > [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        :
> > HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper
> > delta=7h11m45s224ms352µs500ns). 2021-05-19 08:17:11.121  WARN 20520
> > --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper
> > delta=5m29s194ms358µs100ns).

Comment: how often do you need to run the cron?

Comment: i want to run daily at 9 A.M

Comment: these logs dont show anything interesting, this should work just fine.

Comment: Cron looks good to me for everyday 9AM.

Comment: yeah but on the day i restart it working fine. but from next it is not getting triggered. I am running in local server only, Is Zone is mandatory to add ?

Comment: Not mandatory actually but you could give it a try and check.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please check example

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *",zone = "Indian/Maldives")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schedule thread may be hanged or blocked by some consuming-time service. You should first find the blocked code with proper timeout and config a thread pool for the schedule.